# Undecidability and completeness

Tags: logic

friends!
I read in Nolt-Rohatyn-Varzi's *Outline of Logic* that predicate logic is undecidable because it lacks an *algorithmic procedure which reliably detects invalidity in every case*.

Now I also know, from the same book, that the refutation tree method is *complete* and *valid*, in the sense that an argument form is valid if and only if all the paths of the tree are closed; if it's invalid either the tree is finite and a path is open or a path continues to infinity. So, I think we can say that we can detect invalidity through this method since, even if a path is infinite, we notice that we cannot stop it; if we couldn't notice it, I would say that the method is not complete, because it couldn't check all valid forms... I am obviously misunderstanding something.

Moreover, I also read in Nolt-Rohatyn-Varzi's that the set of inference rules of predicate calculus is *both valid (in the sense that the rules generate only argument forms that are valid in virtue of the semantics of the quantifiers, the truth-functional connectives, and the identity predicate) and complete (in the sense that they generate all valid argument forms)*. This creates some more confusion in me.

Last, I read in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_%28logic%29#Relationship_with_completeness) that decidibility doesn't imply completeness: *the theory of algebraically closed fields is decidable but incomplete*, which leads me to wonder how an *algorithmic procedure which reliably detects invalidity in every case* can exist in a system if a method to check all valid forms don't exist (which is what I understand to be completeness). Of course, I misunderstand something, again.

I $\infty$-ly thank you in advance for any help, and happy $2\cdot 19\cdot 53$! ;-)

Comment: There is a difference between completeness of a deductive system and completeness of a theory. First-order logic has a "complete deductive system" but its set of provable formulas is not decidable; the theory of algebraically closed fields is not a "complete theory" but its set of provable theorems is decidable.

Comment: Which is which? I would think that, if a theory has got an algorithmic procedure which reliably detects invalidity in every case (decidability of a theory, as in Nolt-Rohatyn-Varzi's definition: am I right?), then all semantically valid statements are provable (completeness of a theory, I guess): where's my error? I heartily thank you Carl and Mauro!!!

Comment: Is the point that an incomplete decidable theory can formulate formulas that aren't provable by using its deductive system, but there is an algorithmic procedure which reliably detects invalidity _within_ the set of provable formulas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m not familiar with your textbook, so I’ll refer to the exposition of *tableaux method* contained in *R.Smullyan*, **First-Order Logic** (1968, Dover reprint, 1995).

A preliminary comment is needed : unfortunately, mathematical logic uses “completeness” in two different contexts (which ones, it will be clear - I hope - in a moment).

**A)** Let us start with the simple case of sentential logic. Here we have the notion of *tautology* and the method of truth-tables. Truth-tables are an (inefficient but effective) device to test for “tautologuesness”.

When we set-up a proof system for sentential logic, we choose (zero or more) axioms and some (at least one) rules of inference; with an *Hilbert-style proof system*, typically we have *modus ponens*.

We call *theorems* of the proof system all the formulae that are *deducible*, i.e. “produced” starting from the axioms with a finite number of applications of the rules of inference.

There are a lots of different way to set up a proof system; but the basic properties we are requesting to it are the following :

> 1) it  must be *sound* : assuming that all the axioms are tautologies, we want that all the theorems must be tautologies (i.e. rules of inference must preserve the property of being a tautology);
>
> 2) it must be *adequate* :  we want that all the tautologies must be deducible from the axioms (this second properties is usually called *completeness* of the proof system).

With a *sound* and *adequate* proof system, the property of being a theorem is *decidable* : test a formula $A$ with truth-tables; if it is a tautology, then it is a theorem (and some proof of the "completeness" of sentential logic give an effective method to build the deduction of the theorem in the proof system).

As you said, the refutation tree method (or the tablaux method ) for sentential logic is complete (I say adequate), in the sense that if applied to a tautology, all the paths of the tree will close after a finite number of step.

If the tree is finished (and in sentential logic this will always happen after a finite number of steps) with some path that is not closed, the formula is *satisfiable* (and its negation isn’t a tautology).

You must take into account two features of sentential logic :

a) the refutation tree will always finish after a finite number of steps (because at each step the “complexity” of the formulae – in terms of occurrences of connectives - will decrease)

b) the truth-table device allows us to check in advance if a formula $A$ is a tautology or not.

**P.S.** Please, note that, is not true that for every formula $A$, $A$ is a tautology or $\lnot A$ is a tautology. There are formulae, like $p \rightarrow q$, which are not tautologies, and whose contradictory (i.e. $\lnot (p \rightarrow q)$ ) are not tautologies either.

**B)** If now we move to first-order logic, most of the above concepts are still applicable. Instead of tautology, we have the notion of *(logical) validity*. I assume that we are familiar with the basic semantic notion for f-o logic : *interpretation*, *model*, *validity* (i.e.true in every interpretation) and *logical consequence*.

We must note the first difference compared to sentential logic: in f-o logic the device of truth-tables will not work any more; in general, the number of combination to be tested is infinite.

Adding suitable axioms for quantifiers, we will have a proof system for f-o logic that is *sound* and *adequate* with respect to *validity*. Again, the refutation tree method (or the tablaux method ) for f-o logic is complete (I say adequate), in the sense that if applied to a valid formula, all the paths of the tree will close after a finite number of step.

But now, applying the method to a formula $A$ that is not valid (i.e. such that $\lnot A$ is *satisfiable*) we have that either the tree is finite and a path is open or there is a path that continues to infinity.

Again, you must remember that there are *sentences* (i.e.closed formulae) like $\exists x \exists y ( \lnot x = y)$ that are not valid (because not satisfiable in an interpretation with only one object in the domain) and whose negation $\forall x \forall y (x = y)$ is not valid either (because not satisfiable in an interpretation with more than one object in the domain).

Taking into account that we cannot check in advance if $A$ or $\lnot A$ are valid or not, if we run the refutation method with a couple of formulae like the above, and if after a finite number of steps neither of the two trees is finished, we are not licensed to conclude anything.

This is the reason why the refutation method does not violate the (meta-)theorem about the *undecidability* of f-o logic.

Last comment about first-order logic. We said that the proof system is *adequate* when : if $A$ is valid, then $A$ is deducible (i.e. if $\vDash A$, then $\vdash A$) : this result is called Godel’s Completeness Theorem.

It can be stated in a more general form saying that : if $\Gamma \vDash A$, then $\Gamma \vdash A$. All the logical consequences of a set of assumptions are deducible within the proof system.

**C)** About *completeness* of a formalized theory

We say that a formalized theory $T$ (e.g.formal arithmetic, based on the f-o proof system with the first-order version of Peano’s axioms) is

> *negation complete* if, for every sentence $\phi$ expressible in the language of the theory, either $T \vdash \phi$ or $T \vdash \lnot \phi$, i.e. either $\phi$ or $\lnot \phi$ is deducible in $T$’s proof system (see *Peter Smith*, **An Introduction to Godel’s Theorems**, 1st ed, 2007 : pag.2).

We are interested to know if a theory like formal arithmetic is negation complete or not, because with a

> *complete* theory of arithmetic we could in principle use the theory to prove the truth or falsity of any claim about addition and/or multiplication (or at least, any claim we can state using quantifiers like "for all", connectives like "if" and "not", and identity). And if that’s right, truth in arithmetic could just be equated with provability in this complete theory (*P.Smith, loc.cit.*, pag.2).

Godel’s (first) Incompleteness Theorem says that if $T$ has a decidable set of axioms (like f-o Peano’s axioms) and is *expressive* enough (in a specifiable sense) and is consistent , then there is a sentence $\sigma$ that is true in the *intended* model but it is not deducible from the axioms, i.e.is *unprovable* in $T$. Formal arithmetic is NOT complete.

But using the more general form of G’s Completeness Th for f-o logic, we have that the proof system of $T$ is *complete* (i.e.adequate). How we reconcile this with G’s Incompleteness Th for $T$ ?

The reason is that the unprovability of $\sigma$ proves that it is not  a logical consequence of f-o Peano’s axioms. Because the proof of Godel’s Incompleteness shows us (with insight) that $\sigma$ must be true in our “intuitive” domain of natural numbers, from it follows also that there are some models (different from the intended one) where $\sigma$ is false.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I heartily thank you, Mauro. I hadn't understood the undecidability of f-o because I didn't realise that "if after a finite number of steps neither of the two trees is finished, we are not licensed to conclude anything".

Comment: As to the completeness of a theory, I am not sure what a _decidable set of axioms_ (like Peano's 5 axioms, which I know) is. I don't think that means that they can be _proved_ by using f-o logic alone, because it is an extension of it, including the constant 0 and the successor function, but I guess it's decidable by definition, because the axioms are assumed true: am I wrong? And why can we say a sentence $\sigma$ to be true in an intended model (for ex. a formula expressed in the language of Peano arithmetic) if we haven't a tool to verify its truth? I $\infty$-ly thank you...

Comment: When we say that the axioms must be a *decidable set* we are meaning that the set of axioms must be *finite* (in which case it is obviously decidable : it suffice to list them) or, if *infinite* (and this is the case of f-o Peano's axioms, due to the presence of *axiom schema* of induction : the schema "collects" countable many axioms, one for each formula $A(x)$ expressible in the language) they are formulated in such a way to be able to "decide", for each formula $B$ of the language, if $B$ is an axiom.

Comment: About the undecidability, see *R.Smullyan, loc.cit*, pag.63 : "tableaux not only can be used to show certain formulas to be valid, but also can sometimes be used to show certain formulas to be satisfiable (when this formulas happen to be satisfiable in a finite domain). The real *mystery class* consists of those formulas which are neither unsatisfiable nor satisfiable in a finite domain. If we construct a tableau for any such formula, the tableau will run on infinitely, and at no finite stage will we ever know that the formula is or is not satisfiable."

Comment: Excuse me if I add a question here, but it's so inextricably linked to this one that I think it's improper to post another question. I understand that f-o logic is *semi*decidable precisely because it has an adequate/complete proof system: am I wrong? Thank you very much again!

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide - Exactly ! It is **not** decidable because, given a formula whatever $\alpha$ we have no "trest" (like truth-tables) able to ask in a finite amount of steps if the formula is *valid*; but it is *semi-decidable* because, due to completeness, if it is *valid* it must be *provable*; thus, if we "run" a program able to produce all the possible proof in some order, it is enpugh to wait and we will see it "pop up" form the "theorem-machine.

Comment: Very, very kind. $\infty$ thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that the reason of the misunderstanding lays in the statement :

> if it's invalid either the tree is finite and a path is open **or a path continues to infinity**.

You say that

> even if a path is infinite, we notice that we cannot stop it.

But this is not an algorithmic specification: you see with insight that the path "will run forever" ... but how to instruct a Turing machine to detect that this loop defines an assignment that satisfy the formula ?

Answer (score 1):

I deeply thank you, Mauro. I think I have understood what the *completeness* of a theory and the *adequateness/completeness* of a proof system are. Logic tremendously fascinates me and I'd like to follow the study with something more detailed and advanced than the wonderful textbook by Varzi-Nolt-Rohatyn.

As to *decidability*, I think to understand that a theory is decidable by definition when there is a Turing machine algorithm to determine whether a given sentence belongs to that theory, which I think to mean that it is logically impossible that the axioms of the theory are true and the statement false. I know that the decidability of a theory doesn't entail its completeness: there may exist an algorithm to determine whether any given sentence belongs to a theory (i.e. whether it is a logical consequence of the axioms) while we can't check if an arbitrary sentence expressed in the theory's language, or its negation, are deducible once we have the axioms; is it correct my understanding that the sentences that may make the theory incomplete even if decidable are the sentences that aren't logical consequences of the axioms (therefore the algorithm rules them out of the theory) but whose negation is not a logical consequence of the axioms, either?

Comment: *(i)* Yes, *decidability* means that there is a Turing machine algorithm to determine whether a given sentence belongs to that theory, i.e.if it is *provable* form the axioms; in a f-o logic setting, due the completeness of the proof system (every log cons of the axioms is derivable from the axioms) this amount to "it is not possible that the axioms of the theory are true and the statement false". *(ii)* Yes; decidability does not implies completeness (in the sense of G's Incompleteness Th); the G's sentence $G$ is not provable from the axioms (e.g.$\mathsf {PA}$). 1/2

Comment: ... But $G$ is *true* in the *intended* model $\mathbb N$ of $\mathsf {PA}$. So it *must* be false in some non-standard model, because (due to G's Completeness Th), if $G$ would be true in *all* models of $\mathsf {PA}$, by def it will be a *logical consequence* of $\mathsf {PA}$'s axioms (beware! all the argument presuppose the *consistency* of $\mathsf {PA}$). Due to G's Completeness Th, every log cons is provable, and so we would have a contradiction. 2/2

Comment: I suspect ;-) you understand me if I say... $\infty$ grazie!!!