# How is first order logic complete but not decidable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

I know that there are two different notions of completeness and that we shouldn't be surprised that a theory might be complete (in the sense of the theorem of completeness) but undecidable (so incomplete in the sense of the Incompleteness theorem), but I still have a hard time wrapping my head around those two different notions. Could anyone explain clearly how in particular first order logic is complete but undecidable ? And how in general this makes perfect sense for a theory to be complete but undecidable ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know the subtle differences between the completeness theorem and the incompleteness theorem and why they do not contradict each other ? In short : the completeness theorem states that a statement can be proven if and only if it is true no matter which intepretation we use. The incompleteness theorem states that a sufficient powerful consistent theory must be incomplete that is there must be true but unprovable statements.

Comment: You can aee [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626965/undecidability-and-completeness)

Comment: And also [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15525/how-is-first-order-logic-complete-but-not-decidable)

Comment: Thank you very much